# Как сравнить дату из ячейки с текущей?

Tags: javascript

Делаю в Google Sheets + Google scripts.
Необходимо взять дату из ячейки в таблице и сравнить с текущей. Не смотря на то, что в текущей дате обнуляю часы, минуты, секунды и милисекунды и в отладчике значения переменных показываются одинаковыми, результат сравнения показывает их разными.
В ячейке указываю сегодняшнюю дату.

```
// устанавливаем дату и определяем месяц и год
let current_date = new Date();
let today_date = current_date.getDate();
let today_month = current_date.getMonth();
let today_year = current_date.getFullYear();
let clearToday_date = new Date(today_year, today_month, today_date);

// инициализируем таблицу и листы
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let CurrentExp_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CurrentExp_date");

// берём дату из ячейки
let var_date = CurrentExp_sheet.getRange(3,1).getValue();


//  
  if (var_date == clearToday_date){
    testoutput = CurrentExp_sheet.getRange("F6").setValue("1");
  }
  else{
    let testoutput = CurrentExp_sheet.getRange("F6").setValue("0");
  }
```